# Multiple java classes... How to access form event in main?

Tags: java, class, event-handling

Ok here's the scoop. I have an application that uses forms and .java files that allow a user to choose a directory, find all photos in a directory, convert all the photos to byte data and insert the data into a SQL database. I have used:

A main file called Photouploader

```
package photouploader;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 *
 * @author 10339
 */
public class PhotoUploader{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    JFileChooser j = new JFileChooser();
    j.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int returnVal = j.showOpenDialog(null);


    if(returnVal == javax.swing.JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        File dir = j.getSelectedFile();
        File[] matches = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
        {
            public boolean accept(File dir,String name)
            {

               return name.endsWith(".png")||name.endsWith(".jpg");
            }

        });


        if(matches.length==0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No picture files have been "
                    + "found.");
        }
        else{
            fileParser fp = new fileParser();       //create new fileparser
            fp.setFiles(matches);                   //send in all found files
            fp.setFilenames();                      //convert files to names

            NewJFrame JP = new NewJFrame();             //create new form
            JP.setVisible(true);             

            //update lists on the form
            JP.update_Upload_list(fp.getgoodFilenames());   
            JP.update_DNUpload_list(fp.getbadFilenames());


        }


    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"you have not chosen "
                + "a valid directory");
    }
    }
}
```

All my form data is in my class called NewJFrame:

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package photouploader;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author 10339
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        Upload_Button = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        FilesToUpload = new javax.swing.JList();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        DNUpload = new javax.swing.JList();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Upload_Button.setText("Upload");
        Upload_Button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Upload_ButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(FilesToUpload);

        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(DNUpload);

        jLabel1.setText("Files to Upload");

        jLabel2.setText("Files that will not be uploaded");
        jLabel2.setToolTipText("");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(Upload_Button)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 419, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane2)))
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(Upload_Button)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void Upload_ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                             

    public void update_Upload_list(ArrayList goodfiles)
    {
        DefaultListModel model1 = new DefaultListModel();
        for(int i=0;i<goodfiles.size();i++){
            model1.addElement(goodfiles.get(i));
        }
        FilesToUpload.setModel(model1);

    }
    public void update_DNUpload_list(ArrayList badfiles)
    {
        DefaultListModel model1 = new DefaultListModel();
        for(int i=0;i<badfiles.size();i++){
            model1.addElement(badfiles.get(i));
        }
        DNUpload.setModel(model1);

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JList DNUpload;
    private javax.swing.JList FilesToUpload;
    private javax.swing.JButton Upload_Button;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

The FileParser class does all of the lifting for parsing and preparing to send the data to a SQL class. The fileparser is:

```
    package photouploader;
import java.nio.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Compiles July 5th 2013
 * @author Shawn Corliss
 * Company: City of Lethbridge Fire Department
 * This is the fileParser Class
 */
public class fileParser {
    /*var Decleration*/
    private File dir;                                   //Directory
    private File [] allFiles;                           //Holds all files with D
    private ArrayList goodfilenames = new ArrayList();  //Filenames
    private ArrayList badfilenames = new ArrayList();   //Filenames
    private ArrayList goodfiles = new ArrayList();      //Files with Dir
    private ArrayList badfiles = new ArrayList();       //Files with Dir

    /*Accessor Methods*/
    public File getDir(){               
        return dir;                     //Reurun Direcotry
    }   
    public void setDir(File directory){
        dir=directory;                  //Set Directory
    }
    public File[] getFiles(){
        return allFiles;                //Return all Files in array 
    }
    public ArrayList getgoodFilenames(){
        return goodfilenames ;          //Return Arrylist of files >=39
    }
    public ArrayList getbadFilenames(){
        return badfilenames ;           //Return Arrylist of files <=40
    }
    /* This funcition gets all the files found in the matching process
     * The matches are then cloned.
     * The length is checked and if +39 then files are placed in bad arraylist 
     * if smaller then 40 then they are placed in the good file arraylist
     */
    public void setFiles(File [] matches){
        allFiles=matches.clone();
        for (int a=0;a<matches.length;a++){
            if(matches[a].toString().substring
                    (matches[a].toString().lastIndexOf("\\")+1
                    ).length()<40){
                goodfiles.add(matches[a]);
            }
            else{
                badfiles.add(matches[a]);
            }
        }
    }
    //calls setgood and setbad filename functions
    public void setFilenames(){
        setgoodFilenames();
        setbadFilenames();
    }

    /*This function will convert the file path into a file name
     * by parsing out the string to the right of the last found "\"
     * used to push good file names to the list box and for conversion to bytes.
     */

    public void setgoodFilenames(){
        for(int i=0;i<goodfiles.size();i++){ //for each item in the goodfiles
            goodfilenames.add(
                    goodfiles.get(i).toString().substring(
                    goodfiles.get(i).toString().lastIndexOf("\\")+1)
                            );
        }
    }

      /*This function will convert the file path into a file name
     * by parsing out the string to the right of the last found "\"
     * used to push bad file names to the list box.
     */
    public void setbadFilenames(){
        for(int i=0;i<badfiles.size();i++){ //for each item in the badfiles
            badfilenames.add(
                    badfiles.get(i).toString().substring(
                    badfiles.get(i).toString().lastIndexOf("\\")+1)
                    );
        }
    }
}
```

The Issue is that I have an button labeled Upload in the NewJframe class. This button/ event associated with the button press has no knowledge of the already initialized fileparser(`fileParser fp = new fileParser();`) class running in photouploaders main function. My desired functionality is to have:
When the upload button is pressed for the event to shunt back to main an fp.runSQL();
*Please note* 
the fileparser.runSQL is not defined.
Please help.
Can I send data back to main with listener? or should I use an interface? or an interclass?
thanks,
Scorliss

Answer (score 0):

You could try constructing the file parser object in main, and then passing that as a parameter to the constructor of the form class when it is created. This will allow both main and the form class to have access to the same file parser object.

Another option would be to add public methods into your main class that do the file parsing operations. Then you can construct one file parser object in main, and have the form class call into main's methods when it needs to use the file parser object.

Comment: How can you have a form in a separate class from that of the class that has your main function know about an event from a button press? I'm trying to keep my GUI in a separate class from my main and my worker classes.